# Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page in category page. Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2.3

I'm having a problem with the site when I change the language in both categories and products.

Opening the page of a category or product, it shows the writing "Invalid Form Key. Please refresh the page."

Changing language, the site opens the search results page and shows the error message again.

How can I solve it?

Thanks

Comment: you use localhost server ???

Comment: Hi Mohit, no I use Contabo VPS server

Comment: showing error in console or log error ???

Comment: no, and in console show only alert

Comment: I cleared the browser cache and cookies and it seems that the problem has disappeared